# linux ls show seconds for recent files only

Tags: linux, coreutils

linux coreutils ls command shows when using with "-l" option timestamps including hours and minutes for recent files and shows year instead for files older than six months and newer than now. I would like to keep this behaviour regarding old and recent files and would like to add seconds and also tens of seconds to recent files.

```
ls -l /tmp/dir/ 
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 users 0 janv.  1  2004 foo1   <==== keep this style for 
                                                       non-recent files

-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 users 0 juin  14 12:32 foo2   <==== add seconds for 
                                                       recent files
```

Comment: You're expected to demonstrate *some* research effort when asking questions. It only took a few seconds to see from the man page that there's an option for that -- which is more fully documented at https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Formatting-file-timestamps.html

Comment: i read that page before but a little too fast. By reading back my question it shows indeed I did some research. It's not explained that straighforward in the man page. Now i see that is the newline character in the time style that allows for specifying the two styles corresponding to non-recent and recent files.

Comment: I agree the man page isn't easy to understand. Your question would have been fine had you quoted or mentioned which parts of the online documentation you had difficulty with. Now that you have figured it out, it would be useful to answer your own question so future users may benefit from it.

Comment: That's not a matter of understandability. That manual page is not written intuitively enough. I was expecting they emphasize specifically on this mechanism towards recent and non-recent files as they talked about it at the beginning. As I often find inconsistent documentation I'm used to quickly skip the reading.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the lines from the info page of ls:

```
$ info coreutils 'ls invocation'
...
If FORMAT contains two format strings separated by a newline,
the former is used for non-recent files and the latter for
recent files; if you want output columns to line up, you may
need to insert spaces in one of the two formats.
...
the following two `ls' invocations are equivalent:
     newline='
     '
     ls -l --time-style="+%b %e  %Y$newline%b %e %H:%M"
     ls -l --time-style="locale"
```